# How to uninstall Google Chrome?

Tags: uninstall, google-chrome

I decided to try out Google Chrome and see if it was any different from Chromium, but now I can't figure out how to uninstall it.
[image]
That's what I have installed. How to get rid of it is the question.

Comment: It is unfortunate that Ubuntu won't show Chrome in the installed software list or anywhere else when searched as "Chrome", "Google" or "Google Chrome". I HAD to type "google-chrome"... So much for Unity :\

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Run `sudo apt-get remove google-chrome-stable` in a terminal.

Comment: will my bookmark and plugins lost after this ?

Comment: @rab They will stay in `~/.config/google-chrome` (not sure about the name), and other browsers should be able to import them. If you reinstall Chrome without deleting this folder, you should see them.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to purge?

Answer (score 95):

It's usually better to purge:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This will make sure you don't have unnecessary packages remaining, and will remove config files, saving a little space and making sure it won't interfere with other programs or future reinstallations.

Comment: This will not remove the `~/.config/google-chrome`, this has to be done manually through `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome`

Comment: I ran those 3 commands (sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable, sudo apt-get autoremove and sudo rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome), but I still have the downloaded original deb file i.e. google-chrome-stable_83.0.4103.61-1_amd64.deb  (size 68,7 MB) in my directory var/cache/apt/archives. How to uninstall / delete it from there ?

Comment: I found the following a command which can delete all files from directory var/cache/apt/archives: sudo apt-get clean. Source: https://www.howtogeek.com/229699/how-to-uninstall-software-using-the-command-line-in-linux

Comment: Is this `dpkg: warning: while removing google-chrome-stable, directory '/opt' not empty so not removed` warning message normal?