# How to uninstall Google Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, software-uninstall

I know that there are similar questions in Ask Ubuntu regarding uninstalling Google Chrome, like these:

- [How to uninstall Google Chrome?](https://askubuntu.com/q/67047)
- [How do I completely uninstall Google Chrome and Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/q/82186)

But the answers of those posts are kinda outdated.

---

As far as I remember, the steps I followed to install Google Chrome were:

1. I downloaded the 64-bit .deb package from https://www.google.com/chrome/.
2. I installed the .deb package (I don't remember if I installed it using the terminal or GUI, but I guess it doesn't matter).

One thing which is crucial to note, which is mentioned before downloading the .deb package from the website, is (emphasis from the original):

> **Note:** Installing Google Chrome will **add the Google repository** so your
> system will automatically keep Google Chrome up to date. If you don’t
> want Google's repository, do “sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome”
> before installing the package.

[image: Screenshot of Google Chrome's download page (https://www.google.com/chrome/)]

As far as I remember, I didn't execute `sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome` before installing the package .

So as far as I know about Ubuntu and package management, I must remove the Google repository and then uninstall the app. I've heard of `ppa-purge` but I'm not sure if `ppa-purge` is helpful in this case since Google is using a repository, not PPA. Or am I mistaken?

What's the proper way to uninstall Google Chrome (I don't need any configuration files to be left behind)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To completely uninstall Google Chrome do the following:

1. Run the following command to remove Google Chrome along with any dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt purge --auto-remove google-chrome-stable
   ```
2. Run the following command to remove the Google Chrome repository:

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list*
   ```
3. Run the following command to remove Google Chrome directories in your `~` directory:

   ```
   rm -rf ~/{.cache,.config}/google-chrome
   ```

If you'd like to do all the above in one line, you can run:

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove google-chrome-stable && sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list* && rm -rf ~/{.cache,.config}/google-chrome
```

Regarding `ppa-purge`, you are right. You cannot use it to remove the Chrome repository, since it is not a PPA.

Comment: `purge` is for removing configuration files and `--autoremove` is for removing dependencies of Google Chrome only. And the files in the home directory (created by Google Chrome) will not be removed by `purge`. So this command `rm -rf ~/{.cache,.config}/google-chrome` removes them. Am I right?

Comment: What does the asterik (*) do in this command: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list*`?

Comment: When we use `&&`, will the `sudo` be used for all the commands or only for the commands in which it is mentioned specifically?

Comment: 1. Yes. `apt` does not remove any configuration files and directories from `~`, so we have to do it manually. 2. `*` is a wildcard that allows to remove the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list.save` file that exists in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. Also [read here](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm). 3. Each command that we want to run with root privileges must have `sudo`. See [this relevant question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634620/when-using-and-sudo-on-the-first-command-is-the-second-command-run-as-sudo-t).

Comment: Thanks for the info! If you don't mind, can you please explain about `sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome`?

Comment: I don't have much to say. `touch file` is used to update the timestamp of `file`. If `file` does not exist, touch creates it (empty). `sudo touch /etc/default/google-chrome` creates the file `google-chrome` in `/etc/default/`. I suppose that the Google Chrome installer checks for the existence of this file and, if it exists, does not add the repository.

Answer (score 4):

1. To remove the repository, open *Software & Updates* → *Other Software*, click on the repository of Chrome, and click on *Remove*.
2. To remove Google Chrome as well as its configuration files, enter the command:

   ```
   sudo apt purge google-chrome-stable
   ```

You may want also to run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove any unused dependencies.

Comment: **remove** should be **purge**, if you don't want any config files left behind. **autoremove** can remove software that you really don't want removed... so be careful.

Comment: What do you mean by "*Software Sources*"? Is there any app named Software Sources? (If yes, I can't see any such app in my PC.)

Comment: @technastic_tc The name of that app depends on the version and the flavor of Ubuntu. Nowadays it is probably called *Software & Updates* in vanilla Ubuntu with GNOME https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html It used to be called Software Sources before https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7OG4.png (after which I moved to KDE)